Did the prostome last common ancestor (LCA) have deuterostomic development (radial cleavage)?
Traditionally bilaterians are divided in protostomes and deuterostomes. However several very basal protostomic clades have strictly deuterostomic development in more recent papers.

Priapulids have deuterostomic development - paper
Arrow worms have deuterostomic development - paper
Nematomorphs might have radial cleavage - paper
Some have suggested that deuterostomy is an ancestral feature of the urbilaterian

Since priapulids might be the most morphologically similar extant species to the ecdysozoan LCA, this might make it very likely that deuterostomic radial cleavage was the ancestral state of the ecdysozoan LCA.
So my questions are:

Is deuterostomy and radial cleavage ancestral to the bilaterian LCA
Is deuterostomy and radial cleavage ancestral to the ecdysozoan LCA
Is protostomy ancestral to the protostome LCA or is deuterostomy its ancestral state, while protostomy is a derived feature of certain sublieages?

Edit: LCA means last common ancestor

Who is LCA?  Especially in titles, abbreviations other than standard chemical ones should be avoided like the plague.

Sorry, I edited my question. LCA means last common ancestor

Thanks. I could explain at length why it’s best to avoid abbreviations, but perhaps I’ll put it on Meta sometime.

There have been phylogenomic arguments that the urbilaterian was deuterostome-like. They go on to argue that protostomes are a well-supported phylogenetic group, unlike the deuterostomes, and protostomy might be the derived feature. They go on to argue that the urecdysozoan was as one might naively expect protostomic, as they would have been a protostome:

If the deuterostomes are paraphyletic, as some analyses suggest, then the last common ancestor of Chordata and Xenambulacraria was the last common ancestor of all Bilateria; Urbilateria would have had the characteristics that have, until now, been used to define deuterostomes—characters common to Xenambulacraria and Chordata would be bilaterian plesiomorphies.

While the evidence for a monophyletic Ecdysozoan group appears to have been somewhat contentious, contemporary evidence for the monophyly of protostomes still seems to be strong. That said, more recent analysis with additional groups treats the Ecdysozoans as monophyletic even if the exact topology of the group is somewhat uncertain. The characteristics of a possible Ecdysozoan LCA are described recently there, where it is treated as definitely protostomic.
The issue at hand seems to be that nematodes have shown rapid molecular and anatomical evolution, which leads to some confusion in character reconstructions in their parent clades. Your Valentine reference (though I haven't read it in depth) is from 1997, when relatively few sequences were available and the C. elegans nematode was one of these few well studied species.
I think that the ancestral-deuterostomy conclusion is supported but that cleavage pattern is no longer considered diagnostic. Happy to be proved wrong on this point- I have not been very successful in finding many pertinent recent references on cleavage as a phylogenetic character. In one of the more recent papers to cite your Valentine paper, they show in fact that the radial-like cleavage of bryozoans (protostomes) as retaining various spiral characteristics. It is therefore plausible that this trait is relatively plastic across metazoans and the apparent radial vs. spiral differentiation may be a bit more complex than the label:

The fate of the early embryonic blastomeres is thought to be causally related to the cleavage pattern during development [2, 163]. In such case, a change in the cleavage geometry would lead to a change in the cell fates. However, the bryozoan cell lineage illustrates a case where the cleavage pattern and blastomere fates are not evolutionary coupled. We find that the fates of the early blastomeres are similar between M. membranacea and spiral-cleaving embryos despite the modified biradial cleavage pattern.

(the 163 reference is Valentine 1997.)

Thank you, and sorry for the delay in responding. One question - at the top of the answer you said "arguing that the urecdysozoan was as one might naively expect, protostomic, and protostomy might be the derived feature:" - did you mean protostomic or deuterostomic there?

@sashoalm tried to clarify- yeah, I wrote that confusingly. Basically, protostomy is derived relative to deuterostomy, and protostomes form a pretty good clade. Based on that, since the urecdysozoan is a protostomes in a well supported protostome clade, it makes a lot of sense that it would be a protostome.

btw I also asked a narrower question specifically for the urecdysozoan at https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/115104/23100 since it probably can be answered more definitively while this one is a bit more broad and harder to answer.

@sashoalm Hm, the comments on that question make me wonder whether my answer is wrong. Notably it looks like there may be a anatomical vs. molecular phylogenetic discordance here.

Yes, when I talk about protostomes, it can be a bit ambiguous because I have to distinguish between protostomes (the clades) and "protostomy" - the idea of "mouth-first" vs "anus-first" embryonic development. I don't doubt the protostome clade itself (that is spiralia+ecdysozoa), but I was wondering if the ancestral state of both nephrozoa (that is protostomia+deuterostomia) and also protostomia is "anus-first" and radial cleavage.
